# Передача значения DataTimePicker в SQL запрос

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, access

Есть проект Windows Forms на C#, с использованием БД Access. 
Различная сортировка работает стандартных встроенных запросах и вывод

`this.hotelTableAdapter.FillByLonger(this.hoteldbDataSet.hotel);`

в таком формате.

Осталось сделать последнее, это сортировка по дате. Для этого нужно передать выбранную дату в DataTimePicker в SQL запрос.

**C#**

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime result = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    this.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

**SQL**

```sql
SELECT        id, [ФИО проживающего], [Дата заселения], [Дата выселения], [Гостиничный номер]
FROM            hotel
WHERE        ([Дата выселения] LIKE '" + dateTimePicker1.Text"')
```

**Вопрос.** 
Как правильно выполнить сортировку по заданной дате? Правильно ли передаётся параметр? Ругается на To_DATE() в запросе. Как это сделать, до сих пор ещё не решил. Выяснил только, что формат для запроса должен получиться примерно таким #13/11/2013#

Comment: Может не сортировка, а фильтр по дате?

Comment: Да, скорее так.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter`. 
Пример:

```
var ColumnsNames = new List<string>(){"id","Name","DateIn","DateOut","HotelNo"};
List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
string query = @"SELECT id, Name, DateIn, DateOut, HotelNo
FROM hotel
WHERE DateOut = @DateOut";
DateTime _date = DateTime.Now;//как пример значения времени
using (SqlCommand Query = myconnect.CreateCommand())
{
    Query.CommandText = query;
    SqlParameter _par = new SqlParameter();
    _par.ParameterName = "@DateOut";
    _par.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
    _par.Value = _date;
    Query.Parameters.Add(_par);
    using (SqlDataReader reader = Query.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
             Dictionary<string, object> row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
             for (int n = 0; n < ColumnsNames.Length; n++)
             {
                     row.Add(ColumnsNames[n], reader.GetValue(n));
             }
             rows.Add(row);
        }
        reader.Close(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE` для работы с датами не особо подходит. Лучше использовать [специальные функции](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-functions-by-category-HA010131676.aspx).

Допустим мы хотим выбрать все записи, созданные сегодня. Для этого мы используем функцию [DateDiff](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/datediff-function-HA001228811.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010131676), а значение даты передадим как параметр `@Date`:

```
   command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE DateDiff(\"d\", DateCreate, @Date);";
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Date", DateTime.Today);
   using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
   {
      while (reader.Read())
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", reader.GetName(i), reader.GetValue(i)));
         }
         Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
      }
   }
```

Как вы заметили в качестве первого параметра мы передали интересующий нас интервал - день (d). Вы же можете пердать туда год (yyyy), месяц (m) и т.д.

И еще одна тонкость: как пишут на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522924/insert-datetime-parameter-in-access-with-oledb) OleDb не любит миллисекунд, поэтому если вместо `DateTime.Today` передать `DateTime.Now`, то запрос выдаст ошибку (по крайней мере у меня было так)